# How to replace a character with a string in a string?

Tags: string, bash, shell

Given a string variable in bash script with a bunch of newlines '\n', how to replace these newlines with a string - "abc\n"? Or in other words how to insert "abc" in front of every newline?

Comment: See [Substituting part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of ways to "skin this cat" using commands / programs external to Bash. If you only want to use Bash built-ins, however:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Store the newline character.
readonly NEWLINE=$'\n'

## Fetch your content (hard-coded here for the example).
original="one${NEWLINE}\
two${NEWLINE}\
three${NEWLINE}\
four${NEWLINE}\
five${NEWLINE}"

## Peform global substitution.
substituted="${original//${NEWLINE}/ - abc${NEWLINE}}"

## Output result.
echo -e "${substituted}"
```

Based on https://linuxhandbook.com/replace-string-bash/